# valuation vs exponential valuation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I'm having some trouble to understand the concept of valuations (and exponential valuations) and would be very grateful if one of you could tell me whether the following is right:

First of all, there's a difference between a valuation and an exponential valuation (which I also found in Neukirch).

An **exponential valuation** is defined as a map $v_p: K \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \cup \{ \infty \}$ for a field $K$ with the properties that $v_p(x)= \infty \Leftrightarrow x=0$, $v_p(xy)=v_p(x)+v_p(y)$ and $v_p(x+y) \geq min \{ v_p(x), v_p(y)\}$ (1).

In contrast a **valuation** is given by a map $\vert . \vert: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ such that $|x|=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$, $|xy|=|x||y|$ and $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$ or $\leq max \{ |x|,|y|\}$ if it's non-archimedean. (2)

Hence, if I have a map given by $$
|.|_{p,c}: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}, |x|_{p,c}= c^{v_p(x)} \text{if} ~x \neq 0 \text{ and } 0 \text{ if } x=0$$
for some $c \in (0,1)$, $p$ a non-zero prime ideal in the Dedekind domain $A$ and $K$ its quotient field and I am supposed to show that this defines a discrete non-archimedean valuation on $K$, I need to show the properties in (2) but can at the same time use the properties of (1) for the exponent? (The examples speaks of $v_p$ only as a discrete valuation. However, then I fail to show that $|.|_{p,c}$ is a valuation if $v_p$ weren't an **exponential** valuation...)

Thanks for your help and explanations!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If $v_p(x)$ is not an exponential valuation, there's no reason why $|\cdot|$ should be a valuation

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you! That's exactly what I was wondering. Maybe they stated this already somewhere else in the example and I missed it :) Do you maybe know if an exponential valuation is always denoted by $v_p$ and a valuation by $|.|$?

Comment: Yes that is the usual notation (although I'm used to calling $v_p$ a valuation, and $|\cdot|$ an *absolute value*)

Comment: I find the terminology “exponential valuation” strange, since it’s just the negative log of the absolute value.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you - it's much clearer now.

Comment: @Lubin Thank you - I will look this up!